# Combing Two Unmatching Dataframe for Scatterplot

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

```
> postScore

  Var1 Freq
1   -10    2
2    -9    2
3    -8   10
4    -7   30
5    -6   62
6    -5   38
7    -4   84
8    -3  278
9    -2  614
10   -1  138
11    0 2454
12    1  256
13    2  702
14    3  212
15    4   98
16    5   10
17    6   10

preScore  

Var1 Freq
1   -13    4
2   -11    2
3   -10    2
4    -9    2
5    -8    4
6    -7   68
7    -6   88
8    -5  160
9    -4  136
10   -3 1282
11   -2  984
12   -1  796
13    0 4648
14    1  592
15    2  400
16    3  344
17    4   40
18    5   14
19    6   26
20    7    4
21    8    2
22    9    2
```

Desired result: I want to use ggplot to overlay two scatterplots. I need a combined data frame where the columns are var1 (-13:9), y1 (preScore frequency count, unmatching values=0), y2 (postScore frequency count, unmatching values=0). Or, creating two new variables with matching dimensions (unmatched values = 0).

Comment: Using a scatterplot with frequency data seems pretty suspicious. Are you sure that's what your boss asked for? If that's really the case then maybe you need to get him/her educated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not make your intentions clear. From what I have understood, you can use the following code::

```
ggplot() + 
geom_jitter(data = preScore, aes(var1,freq, color="red")) + 
geom_jitter(data = postScore, aes(var1, freq, color="green"))
```